# Laravel как сменить реализацию интерфейса Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory с Illuminate\View\Factory на CustomViewFactory?

Tags: laravel

Как сменить реализацию интерфейса Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory => Illuminate\View\Factory
на Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory => App\View\CustomViewFactory ?

Comment: Через перенаследование... Или я не правильно понял вопрос

Comment: Какая версия лары?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто

1. Создаешь сервис-провайдер вместо дефолтного `App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider`, который наследуешь от `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider`
2. В `App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider` переопределяешь метод

```
    protected function createFactory($resolver, $finder, $events)
    {
        return new App\View\CustomViewFactory($resolver, $finder, $events);
    }
```

3. В `config/app.php` в массиве `providers` заменяешь строку `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class` => `App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class`